# Existence of complex function?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

Motivated by a similar question [Complex-doubly periodic function in two variables?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382480/complex-doubly-periodic-function-in-two-variables), I would like to ask if there exists a non-zero function $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto f(z_1,z_2)$, where $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$ are two complex variables, that satisfies
$$ (\partial_{z_2} + \partial_{z_1})f =0 \text{ and } (\partial_{\bar z_1} - \partial_{\bar z_2})f=0.$$

Notice that such a function $f$ is necessarily harmonic.
$$ (\partial_{\bar z_2} \partial_{z_2} + \partial_{\bar z_1} \partial_{z_1} )f=0.$$

In addition, I require for $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb R$ the periodicity conditions
\begin{gather*}
f (z_1+1,z_2 ) =  f(z_1,z_2 ), \quad  f (z_1+i,z_2  ) = f(z_1,z_2 ), \\
\text{and}\quad
f (z_1,z_2+1 ) =  e^{ik_1} f(z_1,z_2), \quad f (z_1,z_2+i ) =  e^{ik_2} f(z_1,z_2).
\end{gather*}

Such a function $f$ must necessarily have poles, unless $f$ is constant, so what I am asking here is if there exists a function $f$ that satisfies the above differential equations up to a set of lower dimension where the functions exhibits poles and in addition all the periodicity conditions.

Comment: which boundary conditions?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I now renamed them as periodicity conditions. The ones that link translates of $f$ to values of $f$.

Comment: I would use two new variables $x=\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2$, $y=z_1-z_2$, so $f$ is analytic in each of them.

Comment: You really should cite the earlier MO question, so that readers don't have to hunt for it:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382480/complex-doubly-periodic-function-in-two-variables/382716#382716

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'poles'?  As Fedor points out, in appropriate linear coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^2$, $f$ wil be holomorphic wherever it is defined, and that means that it cannot have isolated singularities, because the punctured ball is not a domain of holomorphy.

Comment: @RobertBryant what I mean is the following. Consider the theta function $\theta_{a,b}(z\vert i)=\sum_n \exp(\pi i(a+n)^2 \tau+ 2\pi i (n+a)(z+b))$ then  $g(z) = \frac{\theta_{a',b'}(z\vert i)}{\theta_{a,b}(z\vert i)}$ implies that $g(z+1) =\exp(2\pi i(a-a')) g(z)$ and $g(z+i) = e^{-2\pi i(b-b')} g(z)$ and $g$ is holomorphic away from the zero set of the theta function in the denominator.

Comment: @FedorPetrov thank you

Comment: @PritamBemis:  You write "If $f$ is holomorphic, then $1/f$ is holomorphic away from the zeros of $f$, no?"  That is correct, but a holomorphic function of two variables cannot have isolated zeros.

Comment: @RobertBryant you are absolutely right, my single-variable example somehow made me forget about that. So I replaced discrete by submanifold now. I hope the question is now coherent.

Comment: @RobertBryant, I edited in the [question link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382480/complex-doubly-periodic-function-in-two-variables) you [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382815/existence-of-complex-function#comment973649_382815).  (I assume you meant to link to the question rather than to the answer.)

Comment: @LSpice:  Yes, indeed, the question is what I wanted to point to.  I should have been more careful when I copied the link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is 'yes' there do exist such functions that are non-constant with singularities only along surfaces $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{C}^2$, and here is how one can understand them:

First, it helps to change coordinates, though, perhaps, a little more subtly than Fedor Petrov suggested:  Let
$$
y_1 = \tfrac i2({\overline z}_1+{\overline z}_2 - z_1 + z_2)
\quad\text{and}\quad
y_2 = \tfrac12({\overline z}_1+{\overline z}_2 + z_1 - z_2)
$$
Then $(y_1,y_2):\mathbb{C}^2\to\mathbb{C}^2$ is a diffeomorphism. Using the complex structure on $\mathbb{C}^2$ for which $y_1$ and $y_2$ are holomorphic coordinates, we find that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial{\overline y}_1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial{\overline y}_2} = 0,
$$
so that $f$ is a holomorphic function of $y_1$ and $y_2\,$. Moreover, we have the periodicity relations
$$
f(y_1{+}1,y_2)= f(y_1,y_2{+}1) = f(y_1,y_2)
$$
while
$$
f(y_1{+}i,y_2)= \mathrm{e}^{ik_1}f(y_1,y_2)
\quad\text{and}\quad 
f(y_1,y_2{+}i) = \mathrm{e}^{-ik_2}f(y_1,y_2)
$$

Now, one can construct the general meromorphic $f$ that satisfies these condition as follows:

First, let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be (not-identically-vanishing) meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ that satisfy the period relations
$$
p_1(y+1) = p_1(y)\quad\text{and}\quad
p_1(y+i) = \mathrm{e}^{ik_1}\,p_1(y)
$$
and
$$
p_2(y+1) = p_2(y)\quad\text{and}\quad
p_2(y+i) = \mathrm{e}^{-ik_2}\,p_2(y).
$$
Techniques for constructing meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying such double-periodicity relations are well-known, using $\vartheta$-series or the theory of elliptic curves.  The point is that, if $C = \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is the square torus (which is an elliptic curve), then the above relations on meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ essentially describe the meromorphic sections of two flat complex line bundles $E_1$ and $E_2$ over $C$, i.e., elements of $\mathrm{Pic}_0(C)$.

Given $p_1$ and $p_2$, then the general meromorphic $f$ that satisfies the above conditions can be written as a product
$$
f(y_1,y_2) = p_0(y_1,y_2)\,p_1(y_1)\,p_2(y_2),
$$
where $p_0$ comes from any meromorphic function on $C\times C$, i.e., $p_0$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ that satisfies
$$
p_0(y_1{+}m,y_2)= p_0(y_1,y_2{+}m) = p_0(y_1,y_2)
$$
for any Gaussian integer $m\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Note that the 'singularities' of $f$ occur along surfaces in $\mathbb{C}^2$ that are complex curves in the $y$-coordinates whose images in $C\times C$ are algebraic curves.